# Reuse an OS from stolen computer

Tags: operating-systems

A few years ago, a PC that I had built, was stolen from my home. I still have the Windows7 professional disc, and I'd like to use it on another computer. Is this an issue?   If so, is there any way for Microsoft to tell me where the OS is being used now?  Could help me track down the thief. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an issue?

As long as you hold [the COA](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=windows%207%20COA), then you own the licence.  If (after installing) Windows won't activate, then call Microsoft's activation phone line and they'll help you out.

> Is there any way for Microsoft to tell me where the OS is being used now?

Probably not, and they definitely wouldn't tell you even if they knew.

Comment: Even if Microsoft knew what the ip address was, it would only be based on what they know about the ip address, which isn't very accurate.  The ip address by itself without any other information CANNOT be used to located somebody.  The  represenatives at the activation call center, do not have access to this to what ip address was last used, to activate the license either.  *Typically the activatation is automated, it serves no business purpose, to even log that information.*

Comment: I think activation may fail if the license is OEM, since they are linked to the hardware.